# changing the bitmap color of touched pixel on touch event in android

Tags: android, graphics, pixel, bitmapimage, bitmapfactory

i am trying to developing app on which when user touch the black color its change the color of touched pixels into yellow color 
 but its not working it not change the color 
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  implements OnTouchListener {

```
ImageView iv;
Bitmap bitmap,b;
Bitmap mutableBitmap ,mb;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    mb=bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);
    iv.setImageBitmap(mb);
    change();
    iv.setOnTouchListener(MainActivity.this);


}
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();
    int width = mb.getWidth();
    int height =mb.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    mb.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; ++i) {
        if(i==x*y){
            int redValue = Color.red(pixels[i]);
            int blueValue = Color.blue(pixels[i]);
            int greenValue = Color.green(pixels[i]); 
         if (redValue ==0  && blueValue==0 && greenValue==0)
             { pixels[i]= 0xFFFFFF00;
              Log.v(" action down ", " color change "); }

        }
    }
    mb = Bitmap.createBitmap(pixels, mb.getWidth(), mb.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);   
    iv.setImageBitmap(mb);
        //mb=result.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);
    return false;
}
```

please help

Comment: read about ColorMatrixColorFilter

Comment: can you give a link plz @pskink

Comment: this one? https://www.google.pl/search?q=ColorMatrixColorFilter&oq=ColorMatrixColorFilter&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i60j0l3.1662j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8